# How to order facets in ggplot based on a non-aesthesic variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and am trying to order the facets in my plot by another variable (score).

My data is in long format and sorted by score (range=3-12) but the plots are not sorted by score. Each facet is an id.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
  id age mostlikelyclass impclust weight score
12034   1      Persistent        0      1     3
12034   3      Persistent        1      1     3
12034   5      Persistent        0      1     3
12034   8      Persistent        1      1     3
12034  11      Persistent        1      1     3
12034  16      Persistent        0      1     3
12004   1      Persistent        0      1     4
12004   3      Persistent        1      1     4
12004   5      Persistent        0      1     4
12004   8      Persistent        2      1     4
12004  11      Persistent        1      1     4
12004  16      Persistent        0      1     4
21171   1      Persistent        0   0.99     4
21171   3      Persistent        1   0.99     4
21171   5      Persistent        0   0.99     4
21171   8      Persistent        2   0.99     4
21171  11      Persistent        0   0.99     4
21171  16      Persistent        1   0.99     4
11204   1      Persistent        1   1.00     5
11204   3      Persistent        1   1.00     5
11204   5      Persistent        1   1.00     5
11204   8      Persistent        1   1.00     5
11204  11      Persistent        1   1.00     5
11204  16      Persistent        0   1.00     5
12360   1      Persistent        1   1.00     5
12360   3      Persistent        1   1.00     5
12360   5      Persistent        0   1.00     5
12360   8      Persistent        1   1.00     5
12360  11      Persistent        1   1.00     5
12360  16      Persistent        1   1.00     5
28654   1      Persistent        0   0.99     5
28654   3      Persistent        2   0.99     5
28654   5      Persistent        0   0.99     5
28654   8      Persistent        2   0.99     5
28654  11      Persistent        0   0.99     5
28654  16      Persistent        1   0.99     5
```

I created scoreorder, which has unique scores with the hope that I can order id by levels of the score but the line after turns all my ids to NAs.

```
scoreorder=unique(persistent$score)
persistent$id=factor(persistent$id, levels=scoreorder)
```

Here is my plotting code that gives id facets not ordered by score.

```
ggplot(persistent, aes(x = age, y=impclust, group=id )) + 
geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~id)+
ggtitle("Most likely LLCA=Persistent") + xlab("Age")+ theme(axis.text.x = 
element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
ylab("Cluster")+theme(strip.text = element_text(size=1, lineheight=0.01))
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Facets not ordered by score]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the order from you data.frame you can set in the call to `factor` the argument `level` to `unique(df$id)`, since unique does not change the order of the original appearance in the provided vector. The levels need to be contained in the vector you want to transform into a factor. This was not the case in your code and because of this you got the `ǸA`'s.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y=impclust, color=factor(score))) + 
  geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~factor(df$id, levels = unique(df$id)))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this. The problems is that I have multiple ids with the same score and so this solution overlays ids on the same score facet. (I only provided an edited version of the data but can add more ids).

Comment: @SK77 Then you should add this to your data.

Comment: Apologies - I have added this now.

Comment: @SK77: I changed my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Many thanks! I'm sure your helpful suggestion will get me to what I am trying to achieve but I get the message:                                                            
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 10 needed but only 2 provided.

Comment: @Alex a `dplyr` `arrange(persistent, score) %>% mutate(id = factor(id, levels=unique(id))) -> persistent` might be what the OP ultimately wants (I know they just gave it the  but I thought the comment might help un-confuse others who come to the post since the OP's initial q wasn't clear).

Comment: @SK77 So did it answer your question?

Comment: @hrbmstr That's right. It would also be a cleaner solution compared to changing datatypes within `ggplot()` as I did.

Comment: @Alex - I am just trying to figure out the error message " Insufficient values in manual scale. 10 needed but only 2 provided". Is this related to the number of colours?

Comment: @hrbmstr Thanks for this suggestion  - I will try this also and report back.

Comment: @SK77 I do not get this error but I do not have the whole data set. If you think it could be related to the color just leave color out and look if the error is still there.

Comment: @Alex the dplyr suggestion worked perfectly. I was still getting an error message when I left out colour.